# Meaningful Tests to challenge a Soil Probe

Tags: soil, soil-science

I'm an engineer doing some R&D designing a new product to measure some interesting soil parameters, and integrating a multi-pronged sensor probe to take the measurements. I'm considering making this product just because it's possible to do it. The probe claims to be able to provide measurements for:

- Conductivity [mS/cm in the range of 0 to 10000 with resolution of 10]
- pH [in the range of 3 to 9 with resolution of 0.01pH and accuracy of +/-0.3pH]
- Nitrogen, Phosphorus, and Potassium content [mg/kg in the range of 0 to 2000 with accuracy of +/-40 (2% of full scale)]
- Temperature and Humidity

I had an old pot with some (very dry / loose) dirt that I grabbed from the garage because I wanted to see what the probe measured, and it consistently gave me a reading of 7pH and zeros for everything else. Not very scientific.

How do I create repeatable test soil samples that I can stick the probe into that gives me non-zero / known values for these parameters (besides temperature, which seems reasonable) so I can tell if this probe provides anything resembling useful information?